# Como remover a elevação do ion-toolbar?

Tags: ionic2

O seguinte código abaixo 'constrói' uma barra de ferramentas no topo da aplicação/página. Basicamente um `ion-toolbar` dentro de um `header` que é fixamente posicionado. Pretendo remover a elevação dele mas não estou conseguindo:

### Código

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar >
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title></ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

### Imagem

[image]

Como remover a elevação do ion-toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que conforme este link [Toolbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/#usage) basta usar o `no-border`, assim:

```
<ion-header no-border>
...
<ion-header>
```

Comment: Tão simples assim, que estava lá na documentação. Acho que rolei o scroll muito rápido. Vlw.